# Calling a JS "onclick function" multiple times within a modal

Tags: javascript, onclick, simplemodal

I am trying to figure out how to use the same function 
(closing a modal when clicking out of the modalbox):

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modalEth) {
    modalEth.style.display = "none";
}
```

and

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modalBtc) {
    modalBtc.style.display = "none";
}
```

within to different modals.

Right now, only the onclick funktion "modalBtc" works the way it should. 

I don't have a clue how to bring the first function "modalEth" to life.

It would be great if someone could help me out with a solution.

HTML (1. ModalEth, 2. ModalBtc)

```
<div id="myModalEth" class="modalEth">
<div class="modal-contentEth">
<p>some content</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="myModalBtc" class="modalBtc">
<div class="modal-contentBtc">
<p>some content</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `addEventListener` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: how would that work in my specific case? thank you very much!

Comment: Please add some HTML to your question.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: @Coli added! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myModalEth').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    this.style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById('myModalBtc').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    this.style.display = "none";
}
```

This hides the modal when the user clicks inside the modal.